# Powershell GUI Tool to input folder path, output permissions. Output to TextBox problems

Tags: powershell, user-interface, textbox, acl

I'm writing a simple PS GUI with an input textbox, an output textbox, and a "go" button. User inputs a folder path "\server\share\folder" in the input and clicks the "go" button. Output textbox displays the results of Get-ACL.access.

I have my Form created and my "go" button launches this simple code:

```
        function GetPermissions{

            $Folder = $InputBox.text
            $Result = (Get-ACL $Folder).access | Format-Table IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags
            $outputBox.Text = $Result

        }
```

When I run these commands line-by-line in a console, I get the expected result. When I run them in the GUI, I get the following output in the textbox:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Seems like it's placing the pointers into the textbox instead of the output text. If I send the output to a file by piping to Out-File and then set the outputbox.text to a Get-Content file.txt, I get the expected results, but the formatting goes to hell.

Full GUI follows. Nabbed the template from the guys over at powershellbros.com

```
#################################################### Functions #######################################################


        ############################################## GetPermissions function
 
        function GetPermissions{

            $Folder = $InputBox.text
            $Result = (Get-ACL $Folder).access | Format-Table IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags
            $outputBox.Text = $Result

        }


        function Close{
            $Form.Close()
        }

        



###################### CREATING PS GUI TOOL #############################

    #### Form settings #################################################################
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border
    $Form.Text = "Folder Permissions"    
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1120,330)  
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
    $Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "Zoom"
    $Form.MinimizeBox = $False
    $Form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $Form.WindowState = "Normal"
    $Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
    $Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell.exe")
    $Form.Icon = $Icon

    #### Input window with "Folder Path" label ##########################################
    $InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
    $InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)
    $Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.Text = "Folder Path:"
    $Label2.AutoSize = $True
    $Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,30) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label2)

    #### Group boxes for buttons ########################################################
    $groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,95) 
    $groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,180)
    $groupBox.text = "Controls:" 
    
    $Form.Controls.Add($groupBox) 

###################### BUTTONS ##########################################################

    #### Permissions ###################################################################
    $Permissions = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Permissions.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,25)
    $Permissions.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $Permissions.Text = "Permissions"
    $Permissions.Add_Click({GetPermissions})
    $Permissions.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Permissions)

    #### Close ###################################################################
    $Close = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Close.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,100)
    $Close.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,60)
    $Close.Text = "Close"
    $Close.Add_Click({Close})
    $Close.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Close)


###################### END BUTTONS ######################################################

    #### Output Box Field ###############################################################
    $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    $outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
    $outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,265)
    $outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 8 ,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $outputBox.MultiLine = $True
    $outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)

    ##############################################

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Add `| Out-String` to the `$Result = (Get-ACL $Folder)...` line if that is the way you want it shown in the gui

Comment: That's all it took. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using PowerShell? PowerShell is ill suited for GUI elements like textboxes. Any examples you find of `Forms` end up being C#-styled and not really PowerShell (although it interprets it). Have you considered writing a simple C# application to do what you want (since you are already writing C#-styled code) with better performance? You could alternatively write a [binary cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-binary-module?view=powershell-7.1) in C# to expose your desired functionality to PowerShell.